# wp_mail, sending image attachment with mutilple fields uploading a single image

Tags: wordpress

i know it's a duplicate question, but please be kind with me, i have to solve this. I have a custom form in Wordpress, sending an email template via AJAX. Everything is working fine, except those single fields attachments in the image below. those input fields are triggered by jquery to receive the image and i have tested if the form input file are not empty with Jquery before sending the email. When i put the hard code it's works, otherwise it's not. Please guide me to solve this. Any help would be appreciate.
my HTML form:

```html
              <form id="tratamento_form"  method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                 <div class="form-group ">
                     <label for="name" class="">Nome completo</label>
                     <input id="name" class="form-control  " placeholder="José Aparecido " type="text" name="nome" id="name" autocomplete="off">
                 </div>
              

                 <div class="form-group ">
                   <label for="message" class="" >Selecione 6 fotos</label>
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="file" id="real-file" name="img1" hidden="hidden" />
                        <div class="upload_btn_style">
                          <button type="button" id="custom-button"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                          <span id="custom-text">Enviar foto (jpg, png)</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <input type="file" id="real-file1" name="img2" hidden="hidden" />
                         <div class="upload_btn_style">
                           <button type="button" id="custom-button1"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                           <span id="custom-text1">Enviar foto (jpg, png)</span>
                         </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <input type="file" id="real-file2" name="img3" hidden="hidden" />
                         <div class="upload_btn_style">
                           <button type="button" id="custom-button2"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                           <span id="custom-text2">Enviar foto (jpg, png)</span>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>

                 <input type="file" id="testfile" name="tesinput" value="">
                 <span id="custom-text12">Enviar foto (jpg, png)</span>

                 <div class="form-group ">

                    <div class="row">

                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <input type="file" id="real-file3" name="img4" hidden="hidden" />
                         <div class="upload_btn_style">
                           <button type="button" id="custom-button3"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                           <span id="custom-text3">Enviar foto (jpg, png)</span>
                         </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <input type="file" id="real-file4" name="img5" hidden="hidden" />
                         <div class="upload_btn_style">
                           <button type="button" id="custom-button4"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                           <span id="custom-text4">Enviar foto (jpg, png)</span>
                         </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <input type="file" id="real-file5" name="img6" hidden="hidden" />
                         <div class="upload_btn_style">
                           <button type="button" id="custom-button5"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                           <span id="custom-text5">Enviar foto (jpg, png)</span>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>


                 <div class="form-group ">
                     <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block submit " value="Enviar " type="submit" name="button_submit" id="button_submit">
                 </div>
                 <!-- to be change Hidden value added for WordPress ajax security and to validate function name -->
                 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="field_action_for_ajax_tratamento"/>

                   <div class="msgs-formulario"></div>
                   <!-- Start success message -->
                 <div class="alert alert-success" id="success_message" role="alert">Mensagem enviada com sucesso <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i> Aguarde o nosso retorno!
                 </div>
            </form>
```

```html
function contact_ajax_tratamento() {

    // This calls the javascript we just created for the form validation
    wp_localize_script( 'tratamento_ajax', 'wp_ajax', array(
        'tratamento' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( "ajax_nonce" ) // this is a unique token to prevent form hijacking
    ) );

    // Enable any admin to run ajax_login() in AJAX and POST the form
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_field_action_for_ajax_tratamento', 'ajax_tratamento_form_process' );

    // Enable any user with no privileges to run ajax_login() in AJAX and POST the form
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_field_action_for_ajax_tratamento', 'ajax_tratamento_form_process' );
}

    // Initiate the ajax enquiry form and add the validation javascript file
    add_action( 'init', 'contact_ajax_tratamento' );
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'contact_ajax_tratamento' );

// Function to send the email using the email template
function ajax_tratamento_form_process() {

  ob_start();

     // include THE MAIL TEMPLATE
     include('assets/template/tratamento.php');

     $message = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
  
// HARD CODE IMAGE
// $atachments = array( get_home_path() . '/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Wedding.jpg');

          $uploadedfile = $_FILES['image'];

            $upload_overrides = array( "test_form" => false );

            $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload ($file, $upload_overrides);

            if( isset( $uploaded_file ["image"] )) {
             $file_name_and_location = $uploaded_file ["image"];
             $file_title_for_media_library = $title;

             $attachment = array(
              "post_mime_type" => $uploaded_file_type,
              "post_title" => addslashes( $file_title_for_media_library ),
              "post_content" => "",
              "post_status" => "inherit"
             );

             if( ! is_null( $post )) {
              if ( ! is_numeric( $post )) {
               $post = $post->ID;
              } // if ()

              $attachment ['post_parent'] = $post;
             } // if ()

             $id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file_name_and_location );

             require_once( ABSPATH."wp-admin/includes/image.php" );

             $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $id, $file_name_and_location );
             wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, $attach_data );
            } // if ()



     // $headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';
     $headers[] =  'From: ' . trim( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) . ' <' . trim( $_POST[ 'email' ] ) . '>' . "\r\n";

     wp_mail('example@example.com', "FORMULARIO  TRATAMENTO - SUBJECT", $message, $headers, $atachments);

     $results['feedbacks'] = "All OK!";


     wp_send_json($results);
     die();

}
```

[image: wordpress custom form]